# Firefox web console hangs due to large expanded javascript object

Tags: javascript, firefox, web, console

I'm running the latest Firefox (18.0.2) on OS X and for a little while now, whenever I use the web console interactively with various web apps, it hangs whenever I type a command which returns a large object. The reason is that the console prints out every single line of that object. I would like to know if anyone knows how to disable this behavior and have it just print 'object' or whatever.

Small example (to illustrate things better):

1. I type at the command line:

   > var test = someBigBadassFunctionThatReturnsAHugeObject()
2. The console (on top) prints:

   `timestamp1 | < var test = someBigBadassFunctionThatReturnsAHugeObject()`
3. The console hangs for 30 seconds
4. The console eventually prints:

   `timestamp2 | < { ... } // Big object which takes 1000 lines to print`

I would like for the console to instead print something like (as in Chrome and how it used to before):

```
timestamp2 | > Object
```

i.e. ">", not "<". Folded (or whatever it's called) instead of expanded.

Thanks!